# Using Each Loop in EJS Template and Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a form validation and i am trying to loop the errors in my template but i keep getting error.

In my posts routes i have this

```
router.post('/create',  async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        var errors = [];

        if(!req.body.title){
            errors.push({message: 'Please Add a Title'})
        }

        if(errors.length > 0){
            res.render('admin/posts/create',{errors: errors})
        } else{

        

    let filename = 'Nissan.jpeg';

    if(!isEmpty(req.files)){
        const file =  req.files.file
         filename =  Date.now() + '-' + file.name

        file.mv('./public/uploads/' + filename, (err)=>{
            if(err) throw err
        })

    }


    let allowComments = true;

    if(req.body.allowComments){

        allowComments = true;

    }  else{

        allowComments = false;
    }
    
    const newPost = await new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        status: req.body.status,
        allowComments: allowComments,
        body: req.body.body,
        file: filename
    });
    
    const savedPost =  await newPost.save();
    // console.log(savedPost);
    res.redirect('/admin/posts');
    }
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    

});
```

And in my ejs template with url (admin/posts/create) i have this

```
<% errors.forEach(errors => { %>
 <%-errors.message %>
<% }) %>
```

But i keep getting this error message in my browser

```
ReferenceError: /blog/views/admin/posts/create.ejs:2
    1| <%- include('../admin-partials/head')  %> 
 >> 2| <% errors.forEach(error => { %> <%-error.message %> <% }) %>
    3| <div class="dashboard-col-2">
    4|     <h1>Create Post</h1>
    5|     

errors is not defined
```

What can i do to solve this error message?

When i do console.log(errors) i get this

```
[{ message: 'Please Add a Title' } ]
```

Comment: Are you passing errors to res.render if errors.length === 0 ?

Comment: @AtharvaSharma yes i am passing it to res.render

Comment: Try replacing your loop as follows:
<% errors.forEach(error => { %>
 <%-error.message %>
<% }) %>

Comment: plz share your complete code

Comment: Also, please edit the question instead and you don't have to repeat posting code in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: @AtharvaSharma I have posted the complete code

Comment: @Shivam i have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(errors.length > 0){
            res.render('admin/posts/create',{errors: errors})
```

You are only rendering errors if it's `> 0`, otherwise it's undefined.

Comment: So do i need to add if statement to my ejs template too?

Comment: That's one way. or remove the if statement altogether and send an empty array when there's no errors.

Comment: How do i do this? Because i am still new to express and ejs